# Woocommerce no products found - display custom search results page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to make my first `WooCommerce` store. Unfortunately `Woocommerce` use same template `archive-product.php` to display main shop page and search result page.

My issue is that I created a custom filters, coupons, etc to display when you visit the main shop page but then I don't want to show this content when your search results are "no products found".

The question is then, How to display the "`woocommerce_no_products_found`" (or search results ) in another page different than archive-product.php that it is being used to display the store ? Can I call on functions a template for only search results or to show only the shop instead of both shop and search results using same product-archive file ?

I see I can do an action with this string...

```
 do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found', $wc_no_products_found );
```

On archive-product php I have this...

```
 else {
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
     *
     * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
    }
```

I was thinking perhaps to create a page only for normal store and then keep archive-product as it is. Or the opposite archive-product is for search results and then create a page template for main shop.

I would love something like in archive-product...

```
 if ( is_shop() ) { call this template file myshop.php }
   if ( is_search() ) { call this template file mysearch.php }
```

Any advice highly appreciated. And since first time creating a woocommerce theme, and almost none php skills, please be kind and assume total php newbie. Although I am trying my best to learn as fast as possible :)